# SED replace @{EE3F}

Tags: sed

```
echo "2018/06/12 18:34:58 (TEAM) * @{EE3F}name says: @{BBFF}umm" | sed -e 's/@{EE3F}//g' | sed -e 's/@{BBFF}//g'
```

Works, but not:

```
echo "2018/06/12 18:34:58 (TEAM) * @{EE3F}name says: @{BBFF}umm" | sed -e 's/@{[A-Z0-9]}//g'
```

What did i wrong? Was searching a long time, but could not get a hint.

Answer (score 3):

`[A-Z0-9]` matches just one character of the given type. Use `[A-Z0-9]\+` if your implementation of sed supports it, `[A-Z0-9]\{1,\}`, or `[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]*`, i.e. one or more characters of the type.

You can also use the POSIX class `[:alnum:]` instead of listing the character ranges (but it matches lowercase characters, too), or `[:xdigit:]` to match just hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast answers. Runs like clockwork.